# Gensim mallet bug? Fails to load the saved model more than once

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I am trying to load a saved gensim lda mallet:

```
 ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=n_topics,id2word=id2word)
 ldamallet.save('ldamallet')
```

When testing this for a new query (with the original corpus and dictionary), everything seems fine for the first load.

```
ques_vec = [dictionary.doc2bow(words) for words in data_words_list]
for i, row in enumerate(lda[ques_vec]):
    row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
```

On executing the same code afterward, it is this error that pops up:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/9f371_corpus.mallet (No such file
>   or directory)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
>           at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.load(InstanceList.java:787)
>           at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors.main(Csv2Vectors.java:131)
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Couldn't read InstanceList from file /tmp/9f371_corpus.mallet
>           at cc.mallet.types.InstanceList.load(InstanceList.java:794)
>           at cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors.main(Csv2Vectors.java:131)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "topic_modeling1.py", line
>   406, in 
>       topic = get_label(text, id2word, first, ldamallet)   File "topic_modeling1.py", line 237, in get_label
>       for i, row in enumerate(lda[ques_vec]):   File "/home/user/sjha/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 308, in **getitem**
>       self.convert_input(bow, infer=True)   File "/home/user/sjha/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 256, in convert_input
>       check_output(args=cmd, shell=True)   File "/home/user/sjha/anaconda3/envs/conda_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py",
>   line 1806, in check_output
>       raise error subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/home/user/sjha/projects/topic_modeling/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet
>   import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords
>   --token-regex "\S+" --input /tmp/9f371_corpus.txt --output /tmp/9f371_corpus.mallet.infer --use-pipe-from
>   /tmp/9f371_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Contents of my `/tmp/` directory:

```
/tmp/9f371_corpus.txt  /tmp/9f371_doctopics.txt /tmp/9f371_doctopics.txt.infer  /tmp/9f371_inferencer.mallet  /tmp/9f371_state.mallet.gz  /tmp/9f371_topickeys.txt
```

Also, it seems like the files `/tmp/9f371_doctopics.txt.infer` and `/tmp/9f371_corpus.txt` get modified every time I load the model. What could be the possible error source? Or is it some kind of bug in gensim's mallet wrapper?

Comment: Any progress on this @saurav? I have the same issue!

Comment: The code in this question solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091094/correct-way-to-load-ldamallet-model-with-gensim-and-classify-unseen-documents

Comment: The code in this question solved this problem for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55091094/correct-way-to-load-ldamallet-model-with-gensim-and-classify-unseen-documents

Answer (score 0):

mallet likes to store important model files (the corpus, etc) in /tmp if prefix is unset, and then when /tmp is cleared (say, by restarting) it throws a fit because it needs those files to run. deleting the model and rerunning the algorithm does not solve it- you first must reinstall gensim...

eg

```
conda uninstall gensim
conda install gensim
```

or whatever install manager you prefer.
then delete your saved models (sorry, their corpus etc are already gone...)

important: before rerunning you need to explicitly set the `prefix` param when initializing mallet:

```
prefix = {your chosen prefix dir}
if not os.path.isdir(prefix):
    os.mkdir(prefix)
ldamallet = models.wrappers.LdaMallet({all your other args}, prefix=prefix, ...)
```